# What is the best practice to use ? IplImage , CvMat or Mat?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Which is the best practice to use ? IplImage , CvMat or Mat ?

Is CvMat and Mat are same ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types `IplImage` (C) and `CvMat` (C++) correspond to older versions of OpenCV.
They are still here for legacy reasons, especially `IplImage` for which there are many code samples on the web.

If you start a fresh project, you should embrass `cv::Mat` and the new C++ API that brings a lot of good (kinf of garbage collection, automatic image alloc/dealloc, data sharing between images, machine learning algorithms...). 
This API is also actively maintained, while the others may disappear at some point.
Algorothms that were implemented in C are also being ported to the recent C++ API.

If you have to reuse older code however, you can learn the basics of `IplImage`, and use constructors of `cv::Mat` that work with `IplImage` as input.